# Null in API version Android Studio preview

Tags: android-studio

I updated from Android Studio 2.3 to 3.0 and now none of the previews on the XML editors are shown.

I can see a null in the top bar in the API level selector and it does not give me any option to pick

[image]

[image]

Any possible solution for that?

I tried Invalidate cache and restart but it does not seem to help.

Comment: Can you check your sdk? I think there is a problem about your sdk. You should download sdk platform

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just press "Sync Project with gradle" and enjoy :)
Sync icon is present in the toolbar
[image]

Comment: yep this fixed it

Comment: Saying where is this button would be useful. As a newbie, I have no idea where this button is.

Comment: @Andromelus just to right of AVD Manager. Green circle with blue arrows.

Comment: Worked for me, @Andromelus I added the answer with screenshot.

Comment: Worked for me, sometimes you will find this option under File menu.

Comment: Worked, also gradle icon is changed to elephant with arrow

Answer (score 4):

I resolve this isuue by Syncing Project with gradle files.

In android studio from top toolbar.

choose first File option and click option Sync Project with gradle files.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

choose first File option and click option Sync Project with gradle files. work for me