# android studio - No preview in design tab

Tags: android, android-studio

I am starting out with android studio. Unfortunately I can not even get started. In the design mode I cannot display a preview. In the picture attached you can see I do not have an option of android device. I assume this is one of the reasons.

Can anyone help me trouble shoot this. I have downloaded nexus 5 and 4 in the AVD manager. their screen resolution is 1080p and 768p - My laptop only has 720p could this be an issue?

Very frustrating as I cannot even play around with it.

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDDrg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302565/8052552) , if this is not work please reinstall your android studio or make sure all important sdk tools are download on your device.

Comment: You must ensure that if the project is correctly build or not, we need to full sync the project,  otherwise design is not being displayed .

Comment: too much of a nube to upvote but that worked. unfamiliar with the terminology so did not spot this question. thanks a mill!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure XML representation of layout is error free.
2. Try changing the API levels in the design views.
3. Clean build your project by going to Build > Clean build
4. Ensure you don’t have any file from SDK that is missing
5. If everything is proper still if android studio is not able to render your layout invalidate cache and restart android studio by going to File > Invalidate Cache/Restart